# email configurations for other servers not working

Tags: email

I am trying to send an email verificaton for my site from a server other than gmail.ie support@example.com . But it is not working, and it works for gmail account,

here is my configuration settings:

```
mail.smtp.user="support@example.com"

mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
mail.transport.protocol="smtps"
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"


 mail.smtp.host=mail.example.com
 mail.smtp.auth=true

  mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
  mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
 mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
 mail.login.username=support@example.com
 mail.login.password=pasword.
```

Did i miss anything??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this seems to work fine. Check the connection and U may have to change the security settings of the 'from mail account' manually to allow sending from code. Then the mail will be sent correctly and the receiver may be getting it as a spam mail.